# React performance when many components updating frequently

Tags: reactjs

Not sure this is the correct place for this question, but I need some input from someone experienced with utilizing React with an application that has several components that update at a high frequency. We are evaluating whether we want to use React for a new application. This application will be tracking numerous GPS enable vehicles/drones. I'm imagining there will be a react component to represent each vehicle based on type that will have some telemetry data being displayed as well as CesiumJS map displaying each as well. I'd just like some insight if React can be expected to perform well with such a scenario? We will be limiting the telemetry updates to about 3Hz to the client, but there will potentially be ~100 of them (close proximity, so not loading them all is not an option). If not React, do you have suggestions of another tool? Links to a site with some type of performance comparison graphed would be nice as well since my google foo hasn't produced such a comparison as of yet.

Comment: React can be used, so can vue, angular, svelte or vanilla. Choice of framework isn’t super important. You’ll have to be careful (measure and optimize) around performance no matter which thing you use

Answer (score 1):

First things first, performance depends on many things, your code, any libraries you are using, and the performance of the local machine.

React has useful tools that can help with this sort of thing. One of the risks involved is the high amount of DOM operations can end up taking up so much time in the event loop that user interactions are noticeably slower. With React, if you make careful use of [useTransition](https://react.dev/reference/react/useTransition), you should be able to avoid this, by allowing user interaction to be prioritised.

If you have lots of states that exist at a high level in the React tree, and it updates a lot, you might need to be careful around state management. React Context is a tool you might want to reach for, but be aware its performance characteristics might not be suited for this scenario. Consider using React with a state management library like [Zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand), [Jotai](https://jotai.org/) or [Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/). Those make it easier to manage large amounts of state in a React application whilst reducing wasted operations.

This idea is not exclusive to any framework, but things might be more manageable if the UI updated all the positions simultaneously.

The map library is also going to play a part in this and would need testing in a real-world scenario.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. We can definitely perform batch state updates to allow everything to update at the same time. Will also look at those state management libs.